# Dynamic Programming (how to send a message in the most efficient way)

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time with dynamic programming, I'm new in this, so I hope you could help me with anything you can, the problem is this:

As the Communications Officer of the IKS B'Moth Klingon battle cruiser, your duty is to manage communications in the most efficient way. Assume you need to transmit a message S= s1...sm given as a string of m symbols. For this purpose, you have r different codes. Let b(ij) be the number of bits needed to enconde the i-th symbol of your message in the j-th code. Initially, the bridge transmitter is set to code #1, but you can freely change the code at any point within the message and as many times as you want. To do so, you need to send a control code which is composed of C(ij) bits if you want to switch from current code i to any other code j. Your goal is to determine how to send thee message in the most efficient way (using the least number of  bits).

A) Prove the problem exhibits optimal substructure.

B) find a recurrence for the optimal number of bits required.

C) Build a bottom up dynamic programming algorithm to solve the problem and indicate its complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a 3 dimensional array, and use `previousCode`, `newCode`, and `ithSymbol` as indices. The array will store the least number of bits while scanned upto `ithSymbol` and when it switches code from `previousCode` to `newCode`.

The recursive formula will be:

```
dp(ithSymbol, previousCode, newCode)=min_(i=1 to r)(dp(ithSymbol-1,i,previousCode))+C(previousCode, newCode)+b(ithSymbol,newCode);
```

(Assumed, C(i,i)=0 for all i)

Now you can write the code for yourself.

N.B. This is a naive approach. You can further make it efficient by making the array 2-D as only `ithSymbol-1` is used in any step.

Comment: So if I have to make it in an array 2-D what do I have to do with the ithSymbol -1?